# Issue building program via Cargo build-bpf

Tags: anchor, deploy, build-bpf

Getting an error during Build process with cargo build-bpf on Hello World program.

> error: linker `cc` not found
> |
> = note: No such file or directory (os error 2)

Comment: seems you are not in the correct directory, you would need to add more information to help you.

Answer (score 1):

If `cc` is not found, it may mean that your system needs build tools.  Depending on your platform, you'll need to follow different instructions to install it.

For example, here's how to do it on Ubuntu:

```
sudo apt install build-essential
```